# How to tell serializer the field is in a nested dict?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class Holding(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Fund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    holdings = models.ManyToManyField(Holding)
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "iShares Index Fund",
    "holdings":[
        {
            "holding": {
                "ticker": "AAPL"
            }
        },
        {
            "holding": {
                "ticker": "AMZN"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My serializers looks like this:

```
class HoldingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Holding
        fields = '__all__'

class FundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    holdings = HoldingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Fund
        fields = '__all__'
```

however it doesn't work because `holding` is nested

How do I tell the `HoldingSerializer` that the ticker is inside a nested object?

I've tried

```
class HoldingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticker = serializers.CharField(source='holding.ticker')
    class Meta:
        model = Holding
        fields = '__all__'
```

but I dont think source is used to specify the source in the json; it is used to specify the source from the django models, is that correct?

however I still get the error:

```
>>> serializer = FundSerializer(data=jsonFile)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
>>> False
>>> serializer.errors
{'holdings': [
    {
        'ticker': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')],
    },
    {
        'ticker': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]
    }]
}
```

Comment: The first one is correct, what's the problem you're getting when using it and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to serialize the json into my models, but when I call serializer.is_valid(), it returns false (question updated)

Comment: @AG your first json is not valid `"holding": {` the bracket starts here but there is a missing closing bracket for it. Plus a list with the key holdings having dictionaries inside it with keys being holding doesn't make much sense does it? It should be `"holdings":[{"ticker": "AAPL"}, {"ticker": "AMZN"}]`.

Comment: ah yea sorry, its part of a much larger json which I removed parts. JSON has been corrected.
Yes I agree that `"holdings":[{"ticker": "AAPL"}, {"ticker": "AMZN"}]` makes more sense and my first serializer would work, however the JSON is from an API and I can't change it

Comment: Ah I just realised you mean I should change the json -after- I've received it! Yes that work as well